# sfdx force:org:create fails in v48.0 when I try to have EnhancedEmail enabled

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file, enhanced-emails

I have an issue creating scratch orgs with Enhanced Emails enabled.

Config file settings part looks like this:

```
"settings": {
     "emailAdministrationSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
     }
}
```

Creation fails and reports this error:

```
Error  shape/settings/EmailAdministration.settings  settings/EmailAdministration.settings  Not available for deploy for this API version.
```

From my understanding, the flag should be supported in Spring '20 - documentation still lists it (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailadministrationsettings.htm) and after login, the toggle in Setup is indeed not activated and can be enabled manually.

What am I missing here - any ideas anyone?

Comment: I have had an issue before where the API version in my sfdx-project.json was outdated. I would first off check the api version is set correctly within sfdx-project.json  ```"sourceApiVersion": "48.0"```

Comment: My problems comes exactly from upgrading the project. It used to be 46.0 and the scratch org definition works fine. After I upgrades the project to 48.0, the definition file causes this error, but the Metadata API (to my understanding) lists the syntax and entity as a valid option in v. 48.0. That's why I'm very puzzled,

Comment: Can you confirm the sfdx command you are using to create the scratch org - i just appended these settings to my definition file and it created a scratch org as expected.

Salesforce release: Spring '20 Patch 10.4 
SFDX version no: sfdx-cli/7.47.0-0e5d18732f darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3

Command used
```sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a enhancedEmailTest --targetdevhubusername mydevhubalias --json```

Comment: Interesting. My CLI: sfdx-cli/7.47.0 darwin-x64 node-v12.14.1

The --json still gave me a good pointer, as the error is thrown from the salesforce-alm  node module. Maybe I have messed something up in terms of node modules vs. old standalone installation...

Comment: Hmm, the problem was not in outdated modules... but now I have a clean nvm / node / npm installation :-) 
`sfdx-cli/7.48.0 darwin-x64 node-v13.9.0
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.1.5 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 2.2.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.7 (core)
generator 1.1.2 (core)`

Comment: salesforcedx 48.3.1 (core)
├─ salesforcedx-templates 48.4.0 (core)
├─ salesforce-alm 48.4.0 (core)
└─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.5 (core)

Comment: Seems to be related to https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/323